# How to force double value to a specific number of digits in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have this table

```
+------------+
|value       |
+------------+
|        2.3 |
|        2.0 |
|        1.55|
+------------+
```

I want the actual output value to always have two digits at the end, to something like

```
+------------+
|value       |
+------------+
|        2.30|
|        2.00|
|        1.55|
+------------+
```

This is just for the output part, so I can convert it to String to make it easier, I'm trying to create a regexp to do this, but I feel there should be an easier way to do it with the double value.

Any tips will help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the column type to decimal.

```
import spark.implicits._

Seq(2.3, 2.0, 1.55).toDF()
   .withColumn("value", 'value.cast("decimal(38, 2)"))
   .show()

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| 2.30|
| 2.00|
| 1.55|
+-----+
```